# scipy sparse matrix negative column index found

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn, scipy, sparse-matrix

I am trying to run the `PolynomialFeatures` from `sklearn` with a large sparse matrix as input:

```
[1] x
>>> <11967295x120006 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int64'>'
    with 55375058 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>

[2] from sklearn.preprocessing import PolynomialFeatures
[3] pf = PolynomialFeatures(interaction_only=True, include_bias=False, degree=2)
[4] xinter = pf.fit_transform(x)
```

And got the error `ValueError: negative column index found`:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-78-dc5dc18d59d2> in <module>
      1 start = time.time()
----> 2 xinter = pf.fit_transform(x)
      3 end = time.time()

/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/base.py in fit_transform(self, X, y, **fit_params)
    551         if y is None:
    552             # fit method of arity 1 (unsupervised transformation)
--> 553             return self.fit(X, **fit_params).transform(X)
    554         else:
    555             # fit method of arity 2 (supervised transformation)

/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/preprocessing/data.py in transform(self, X)
   1523                     break
   1524                 to_stack.append(Xp_next)
-> 1525             XP = sparse.hstack(to_stack, format='csr')
   1526         elif sparse.isspmatrix_csc(X) and self.degree < 4:
   1527             return self.transform(X.tocsr()).tocsc()

/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scipy/sparse/construct.py in hstack(blocks, format, dtype)
    463 
    464     """
--> 465     return bmat([blocks], format=format, dtype=dtype)
    466 
    467 

/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scipy/sparse/construct.py in bmat(blocks, format, dtype)
    572         for j in range(N):
    573             if blocks[i,j] is not None:
--> 574                 A = coo_matrix(blocks[i,j])
    575                 blocks[i,j] = A
    576                 block_mask[i,j] = True

/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scipy/sparse/coo.py in __init__(self, arg1, shape, dtype, copy)
    170                     self._shape = check_shape(arg1.shape)
    171                 else:
--> 172                     coo = arg1.tocoo()
    173                     self.row = coo.row
    174                     self.col = coo.col

/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scipy/sparse/compressed.py in tocoo(self, copy)
   1015         from .coo import coo_matrix
   1016         return coo_matrix((self.data, (row, col)), self.shape, copy=copy,
-> 1017                           dtype=self.dtype)
   1018 
   1019     tocoo.__doc__ = spmatrix.tocoo.__doc__

/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scipy/sparse/coo.py in __init__(self, arg1, shape, dtype, copy)
    196             self.data = self.data.astype(dtype, copy=False)
    197 
--> 198         self._check()
    199 
    200     def reshape(self, *args, **kwargs):

/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scipy/sparse/coo.py in _check(self)
    289                 raise ValueError('negative row index found')
    290             if self.col.min() < 0:
--> 291                 raise ValueError('negative column index found')
    292 
    293     def transpose(self, axes=None, copy=False):

ValueError: negative column index found
```

This does not look right because the `col` index type is `int64`:

```
> /venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scipy/sparse/coo.py(291)_check()
    289                 raise ValueError('negative row index found')
    290             if self.col.min() < 0:
--> 291                 raise ValueError('negative column index found')
    292 
    293     def transpose(self, axes=None, copy=False):

ipdb> self.col.max()
2147482788
ipdb> self.col.dtype
dtype('int64')
ipdb> self.col.min()
-2147480639
```

I am using the following versions:

```
scipy.__version__
'1.3.1'

sklearn.__version__
'0.21.2'
```

I appreciate any help to figure out this issue!

Comment: What has `int64` (which can indeed take negative values) has to do with the issue?

Comment: @desertnaut, the row and column indices of a sparse matrix will be `int64` dtype arrays.

Comment: @desertnaut, I believe the negative index was caused by int overflow, as you can see the `col.max()` is at the max of `int32`. However, since the dtype of col index is `int64`, it should not overflow at this point.

Comment: About the only thing you can do is verify that the input matrix is valid. 
 for example run a `csr` check: `x.check_format(full_check=True)`.  Beyond that you are at the mercy of what `sklearn` is doing with the `fit_transform.  Your `scipy` version is a bit out of date, but not bad.  You could also review `sklearn` github issues.

Comment: @hpaulj, checked and nothing was printed out. I assume the matrix passed the check.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is discussed in [sklearn github repo](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/16803) and the solution is merged to the main branch. I have received the same error and upgrading scikit-learn to v1.3.2 solved it.